# Calculate page generation time - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this out of the box.

I need the time it takes to generate a web page within the site templates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to write how long it takes you to write a comment inside that comment?

Comment: @Dominic: haha good point! I thought about this, but despite that I need to provide the closest value that I can

Answer (score 3):

It's not out of the box, but the [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) displays stats on how long various elements of the page rendering process took.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one built in, but this middleware promises to do what you want: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/358/